# Fast way to get the value of a column element from another dataframe in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have following dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'Col_2': ('a', 'c', 'd')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col_3': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 'Val': (1, 2, 3, 4)})
df1:
Col_1 Col_2
0     a     a
1     b     c
2     c     d

df2:
  Col_3  Val
0     a    1
1     b    2
2     c    3
3     d    4
```

I am trying to add two columns to add the values of a, b, c and d from df2. Here is the code that I have, but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it for large size datasets.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Col_1', right_on='Col_3').merge(df2, left_on='Col_2', right_on='Col_3')

df3:
 Col_1 Col_2 Col_3_x  Val_x Col_3_y  Val_y
0     a     a       a      1       a      1
1     b     c       b      2       c      3
2     c     d       c      3       d      4
```

If using merge is efficient enough, is there any way to stop duplicating the `Col_3_x`  and `Col_3_y`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the join is on a single column, you can `map` twice:

```
s = df2.set_index('Col_3')['Val']  # Use this to map
for col in df1.columns:
    df1[f'Val_{col}'] = df1[col].map(s)

print(df1)
  Col_1 Col_2  Val_Col_1  Val_Col_2
0     a     a          1          1
1     b     c          2          3
2     c     d          3          4
```

---

If the join is on multiple columns then you can `map` with tuples as the keys, though creating them can be slow. `merge` is more naturaly and to avoid duplication `rename` so the keys are the same in both DataFrames.

```
for col in ['Col_1', 'Col_2']:
    df1 = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'Col_3': col, 'Val': f'Val_{col}'}),
                    how='left', on=col)
```